# Snowflake PIVOT - Invalid Identifier for table that exists

Tags: pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting the following error in a PIVOT that doesn't make sense. I can select the column in the same way, and it works. I've tried changing to upper case and putting double quotes around the tables in the PIVOT statement....nothing seems to work.

SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 8 invalid identifier 'ITEM_ATTR.ATTR_VALUE'

```
SELECT *

FROM dw.mes_item_attr_dim AS item_attr, dw.mes_attr_dim AS attr

PIVOT

(

  MAX(item_attr.attr_value) FOR attr.attr_desc IN ('CAN_CODE')

)

WHERE attr_grp = 1 AND item_attr.attr_id = attr.attr_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this by using a CTE for the JOIN

-- untested

```
WITH X as 
(
  SELECT item_attr.attr_value,attr.attr_desc,attr_grp, item_attr.attr_id , attr.attr_id
  FROM mes_item_attr_dim AS item_attr, mes_attr_dim AS attr
  WHERE attr_grp = 1 AND item_attr.attr_id = attr.attr_id
) select * from X
PIVOT(MAX(attr_value) FOR attr_desc IN ('CAN_CODE')) as tst;
```